# spring neo4j optional orElse() error

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I´m using the example from [spring-boot-neo4j](https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-neo4j-example/blob/master/src/main/java/guru/springframework/services/ProductServiceImpl.java) , the class ProductServiceImpl on line 37, has a orElse() method.

```
   public Product getById(Long id) {
        return productRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
```

In my case I don´t know why it is marked as error saying that "Cannot resolve method orElse(null), [image: error]

why so? what am I missing?

This is my Product domain

```
@NodeEntity
public class Product {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String imageUrl;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

 //getters and setters
    }
```

My repository

```
import guru.springframework.domain.Product;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository;

public interface ProductRepository extends GraphRepository<Product> {

    Product findById(Long id);

    Product deleteById(Long id);
}
```

Service

```
import guru.springframework.commands.ProductForm;
import guru.springframework.converters.ProductFormToProduct;
import guru.springframework.domain.Product;
import guru.springframework.repositories.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

 private ProductRepository productRepository;
    private ProductFormToProduct productFormToProduct;

    @Autowired
    public ProductServiceImpl(ProductRepository productRepository, ProductFormToProduct productFormToProduct) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
        this.productFormToProduct = productFormToProduct;
    }

    //some methods..

     @Override
    public Product getById(Long id) {
        return productRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
        //return productRepository.findById(id);
    }

   }
```

The pom file is the same as [pom.xml](https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-neo4j-example/blob/master/pom.xml)

Comment: Does a simple `mvn test` work in the terminal? It does on my machine with your project the same as in my IDE. Please check your maven dependencies used by your IDE (Refresh/Update dependencies).

Comment: i'm using intellij , I refreshed the dependencies and I still have the same error. In the terminal , I don't have maven installed to use it via command. Do I need it?

Comment: Not necessarily because IntelliJ bundles a version of maven. I have tested your project again on a machine with an empty local maven repository and it also works out of IntelliJ. I am pretty sure that it is a setting/config problem at your side, but I do not have any clue what it might be. Maybe it would be a good idea to try your build with a standalone version of maven on the command line. Additional it would be interesting if you see the SDN 5.0.2 dependencies in the project view.

Comment: I see, Thank you for taking the time reviewing the application, let see if I can make it work ;)